# std::is_move_assignable_v false though there is a move assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++17, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

**Context:** I've a class `DLXMatrix` with some attribute which are vector of some local class called `Header`. Each `Header` holds some pointer on some other `Header` which refer to elements of the same vector (think of a structure which is both a vector and a doubly linked list). As a consequence, I cannot use the default copy constructor and assignment operators since they would point to the original elements and not the copy. Note: I'm making sure that the vector is never resized or moved in the memory.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class DLXMatrix {
  private:
    struct Header {
        Header *left, *right;
    };
    std::vector<Header> heads;
  public:
    DLXMatrix() = delete;
    explicit DLXMatrix(size_t nb_col);
    DLXMatrix(const DLXMatrix &);
    DLXMatrix &operator=(DLXMatrix other);
    DLXMatrix(DLXMatrix &&) = default;
    DLXMatrix &operator=(DLXMatrix &&other) = default;
    ~DLXMatrix() = default;
};

static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<DLXMatrix>::value);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable<DLXMatrix>::value);
```

If I'm not mistaken, though I defined custom copy and assigment operator, the default destructor, move constructor and move assignment copy should work as expected without leaking.
Now, I'd like to use `std::swap` but it refuses to compile because my class is not move assignable:

```
dlx_matrix.cpp:257:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement
      'std::is_move_assignable_v<DLX_backtrack::DLXMatrix>'
    static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<DLXMatrix>);
```

So my questions are:

- is this a reasonable way of doing things ?
- why is `DLXMatrix` not move assignable ?

If it matters I'm compiling with g++ 7.5.0 and clang++ 6.0.0 with standard c++17.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why the copy assignment operator doesn't take a `const DLXMatrix &`?  [Changing it resolves the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/5jTEd6) (I don't have a good explanation why).

Comment: I noticed the same thing.  Looks like something about that is getting in the way.  Which is really weird, considering copy and swap is a known idiom.

Comment: See e.g. why this messes things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961719/overload-resolution-between-object-rvalue-reference-const-reference. I don't know how `is_move_assignable` is implemented, but it probably doesn't even see your actual move assignment operator.

Comment: @IlCapitano : I needed a copy so I figured out that calling the copy constructor during the function call spared one line. The code is working now. Thanks for the catch ! I'll gladly accept it if you write a proper answer !

Comment: It looks like the malformed copy constructor hides the move constructor.  Results may vary from compiler to compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer following the indication of @IlCapitano.

In the implementation of `operator=` I needed to do a copy and decided to perform it thanks to a call-by-value. So the prototype was

```
DLXMatrix &operator=(DLXMatrix other);
```

instead of the standard

```
DLXMatrix &operator=(const DLXMatrix &other);
```

This call-by-value form is not recognized as a proper copy assignment operator by the compiler/library.