# Choosing function overload with rvalue references

Tags: c++, overloading, move, rvalue-reference

This is clearly not the same question as [Overload resolution between object, rvalue reference, const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961719/overload-resolution-between-object-rvalue-reference-const-reference). Please do not close this question. In the previous question an `int` is being passed while here an `int &&` is being passed.

I thought I understood rvalue references but evidently I am missing something when it comes to function overloading. Given the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void afunc(int)
    {
    std::cout << "\nafunc(int)\n";
    }
    
void afunc(int &&)
    {
    std::cout << "\nafunc(int &&)\n";
    }
    
int main()
  {
  
  int i = 0;
  
  afunc(std::move(i));
  }
```

I would have assumed that the second call to `afunc` would be chosen, but instead I get that the error that the call to `afunc` is ambiguous. Since `std::move(i)`, as I understand it, creates an rvalue reference to `i`, an `int`, I do not understand why the second call to `afunc` does not match exactly. Can someone please explain what I am understanding that is wrong ?

Comment: Note that making your first function signature into `void afunc(int&)` **will** allow resolution.

Comment: Obviously. But that is not what I am asking.

Comment: If the duplicate target doesn't address your concerns, please edit the question to clarify which part is still confusing you.

Comment: The [answer from Andrew Tomazos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961890/924299) seems to say that `int` and `int&&` are "indistinguishable", meaning the calls are "ambiguous" and that "there is no best match". How does your question differ?