# How to handle variable number of arguments and string variables

Tags: c++, function-templates

In the following code, the variable number of arguments assume a string variable in itself but it does not happen for string literals

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename MyType, typename StringT=std::string, typename... ArgsT,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string, StringT>>>
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function(const StringT& name, ArgsT&&... args) {
      std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl;
      auto t = std::make_shared<MyType>(5);
      return t;
  }
  
template <typename MyType, typename... ArgsT>
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function(ArgsT&&... args) {
      auto t = my_function<MyType>("default name", std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
      return t;
  }

int main() {
    std::string myvar= "something";
    auto ret = my_function<int>("something");
    auto ret2 = my_function<int, std::string>(myvar);
    auto ret3 = my_function<int>(myvar);
    auto ret4 = my_function<int>(42);// 42 could be anything

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
name: something
name: something
name: default name
name: default name
```

How to avoid this and call the first constructor in the third `my_function<int>(myvar)` call as well? How to print "something" in all the cases except the last one?

Comment: The question here seems to basically be "Why is `template <typename MyType, typename... ArgsT>` a better match than `template <typename MyType, typename StringT=std::string, typename... ArgsT, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string, StringT>>>`?" Understand that and you should be able to work around it.

Comment: The **problem** is that for the call `my_function<int>(myvar)` the generic version `my_function(ArgsT&&... args)` is **better match** because it doesn't require a *conversion to const* for it's argument. That is, the first overload `my_function(const StringT& name, ArgsT&&... args)` requires a *conversion to const* for its first parameter `name` and hence it is **worse match** than the generic version `my_function(ArgsT&&... args)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SFINAE to *enable* the 1st function only if `std::string` can be constructed from the 1st parameter type. So, you should then use SFINAE to *disable* the 2nd function for the same parameter type, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename MyType, typename StringT=std::string, typename... ArgsT,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string, StringT>>>
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function(const StringT& name, ArgsT&&... args) {
      std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl;
      auto t = std::make_shared<MyType>(5);
      return t;
  }
  
template <typename MyType, typename Arg1T, typename... ArgsT,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<std::string, Arg1T>>>
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function(Arg1T&& arg1, ArgsT&&... args) {
      auto t = my_function<MyType>("default name", std::forward<Arg1T>(arg1), std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
      return t;
  }

int main() {
    std::string myvar= "something";
    auto ret = my_function<int>("something");
    auto ret2 = my_function<int, std::string>(myvar);
    auto ret3 = my_function<int>(myvar);
    auto ret4 = my_function<int>(42);// 42 could be anything

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
name: something
name: something
name: something
name: default name
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/R99TblqID)

If you need to handle the case where no input parameters are passed in, then simply add a 3rd overload for that case:

```cpp
template <typename MyType>
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function() {
      auto t = my_function<MyType>("default name");
      return t;
  }
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/406Z7q9-u)

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that for the call `my_function<int>(myvar)` the generic version `my_function(ArgsT&&... args)` is **better match** because it doesn't require a *conversion to const* for it's argument. That is, the first overload `my_function(const StringT& name, ArgsT&&... args)` requires a *conversion to const* for its first parameter `name` and hence it is **worse match** than the generic version `my_function(ArgsT&&... args)`.

To show this, below is a [contrived example](https://godbolt.org/z/GGdGEe7hr):

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T, typename... Args> void func(const T&, Args&&...)
{
std::cout << "const T& version";
}
template<typename... Args> void func(Args&&...)
{
 std::cout << "Without const version";
}
int main()
{
    func(4);   //prints Without const version
}
```

---

##### Solution

One way to solve this is to pass `name` by value by removing the low-level const from `name` as shown below:

```
template <typename MyType, typename StringT=std::string, typename... ArgsT,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string, StringT>>>
//------------------------------------vvvvvvv------------------------->removed const & from here
  std::shared_ptr<MyType> my_function(StringT name, ArgsT&&... args) {
      std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl;
      auto t = std::make_shared<MyType>(5);
      return t;
  }
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j6Y8n4bfG)

Comment: That's interesting. Why is `const` creating this? Any reason it is not a better match?

Comment: @soham It is not a better match because it requires a "conversion to const" while the other one don't. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961890/12002570) that should clear things up.